# d3 plotting multiple time series with different time scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I'm new to d3 (& javascript) and want to ask if I can plot 2 different time series on the same chart if they have different time scales - e.g. one is monthly data and the other is yearly

Does d3 handle the x-axis ticks automatically?

Can you point me to some example code?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 for an example of Multi-Series Line Chart.

Comment: This questions was asking for multiple x-y pairs, not 1 x for multiple y values.

Comment: @user3591836 I am wondering about the same thing .. did you find any good answer for your question?